# Why is my JTable not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

My JTable is not showing up. I don't have a clue why. maybe you can help me. I have a Window Class which has a right panel and the right panel should show a table with model data. I have used dummy data to start off with such as Month and Days.

Here is the Right Panel Class

```
import model.*;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class RightPanel extends JPanel implements View
{
    private TablePanel songsnartists = new TablePanel();
    Shop shop;

    public RightPanel(Shop ourShop)
    {   
        shop = ourShop;
        setup();
        build();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setup()
    {   
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    }

    private void build()
    { 
        add(songsnartists);
    }

    public void update()
    {}
}
```

/* simple enough so far just trying to add the table panel to my right panel */

Here is the TablePanel class that I created. It inherits JTable and uses a private class MyTableModel which inherits AbstractTableModel in order for me to make an uneditable table.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class TablePanel extends JTable
{
    //private int ROWS = 3;
    //private int COLUMNS = 2;
    private final String [][] data = {{"Jan", "31"}, {"Feb","28"},{"Mar","31"}};
    private final String[] headers = {"Month", "Days"};
    JTable table;


    public TablePanel()
    {
        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(data, headers));
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        //header.setBackground(Color.blue);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Month", "Days"};
        private String[][] data = {{"Jan", "31"}, {"Feb","28"},{"Mar","31"}};

        public MyTableModel(String [][] data, String [] header)
        {
            int rows, cols, rowCounter, colCounter;

            rows = getRowCount();
            cols = getColumnCount();

            for (rowCounter=0; rowCounter < rows; rowCounter++)
                {
                    for (colCounter=0; colCounter < cols; colCounter++)
                        {
                            setValueAt(data[rowCounter][colCounter],rowCounter,colCounter);
                        }
                }           
        }


        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int c) 
        {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the abstract methods are overridden in the private class. Can anyone help me to show me why my JTable is not showing up?

Comment: So... where do you want the JTable to show up?

Comment: are you adding a instance of RightPanel onto your frame? As it is now, you are adding the TablePanel onto RightPanel, but you are not adding RightPanel anywhere

Answer (score 4):

- read tutorial [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- put [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) to the [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- don't forget to put `JScrollPane` to the [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) by using proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), I can't see there that you added `JTable` to the `JPanel`, not sure if new `GridLayout(3,2)` could be proper `LayoutManager` for `JTable view`

Comment: I ve fixed this problem but it was ages ago. I forgot how I did it. If I  remember I will post the answer here.

Comment: Sorry people I can not provide any further information. This was ages ago and I forgot about. I cant remember exactly how I fixed things. Lazy me.